# Compare value in char** array

Tags: c

I am working on a C project. I am new to C so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I have a `char **` which is an array that contains various values. Out of all the values I have no problem what the values contain except for one where it keeps on core dumping on strcmp.

Below is my code:

```
if (strcmp(reportParameterArray[P_UNIQUECOLS],'Y') != 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

`P_UNIQUECOLS` is an enum which is the index of where to retrieve the value from. If I look at the value in GDB I can see that it either contains `Y` or `N` as it should but for some reason the app is crashing.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `"Y"` which is a string literal, not `'Y'` which is a `char` literal, as [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) takes two `const char*` arguments.

Compile with warnings at the high level and don't ignore them (preferably treat them as errors).

Comment: And pay attention to the compiler warnings, or get a better compiler!

Comment: Thanks this worked. There weren't any compiler warnings or errors. This is a really old server I am having to build on so the compiler isn't great

Answer (score 2):

`'Y'` is a single character, `strcmp` expects a pointer. If your compiler is not giving you at least a warning, you're not using it with the right options.

Use `"Y"` instead of `'Y'`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, strcmp takes both parameters as string.

If the application is crashing, and getting segmentation fault that means you are accessing some unauthorized memory location. Check whether "reportParameterArray" you have allocated memory or not.